# Untimely death, heaven/hell, ghosts and rebirth

Tags: rebirth, death

If there is an untimely death of a person before a person is scheduled to die or if a person commits suicide before he is scheduled to die, does he become a ghost and has to live as a ghost until his time arrives to go to heaven or hell? And after heaven or hell, does he enter into a new life?

Comment: Ghosts are formed generally due to unfulfilled desires. I think death is predestined to us whatever it is, natural or unnatural. It is said our life on this earth has fixed no. of breaths.

Comment: If someone becomes a ghost, it is not for a limited period post which they get liberated and go to heaven/hell. A ghost's lifetime is undefined/virtually infinite. One way to liberate a ghost is to do bhagavata saptaha parayana in their name. The ghost must listen to the paranaya.

Comment: What is bhagavata saptaha parayana?

Comment: dhandukari story mentioned by sage vyasa tells about that it relieves the sprit of prethathva.. and progress to next stage @user3750229 seven days srimad bhagavata sravana should be done by learned brahmin in the home of deceased